# Installing RSpec Bundle for TextMate

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am getting started with Ruby development and bought a MAC few days ago. I am having a hardtime installing the RSpec bundle on my TextMate. When I type the following command:

John-Doe-MacBook-Pro:Users johndoe$ cd ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/TextMate/Bundles/

I get the following:

-bash: cd: /Users/johndoe/Library/ApplicationSupport/TextMate/Bundles/: No such file or directory

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First install git:
  http://git-osx-installer.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.2-intel-leopard.dmg

From the terminal:

```
mkdir ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate
mkdir ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/
git clone git://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle.git RSpec.tmbundle
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```